# How can you tell if a resistor is SMD or THT?

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, through-hole

In my small project, every type of component I am using (inductors, capacitors, ICs) has something to indicate that is a surface mount type except for the resistors. I need to know so I can select the proper footprint. Another reason why it might matter is that it may be more costly for me to order the final pcb if there are 2 different processes used. I had the information below for one of the resistors (the others are similar) and normally there is a row for specifying the mounting type (maybe for resistors it is the 'Supplier Device Package' row that was left blank), can any of this information be used to figure it out in a way I don't know of? I was thinking that they are all THT because they have their length directly specified instead of a model type which is a number like 0805 for one of my SMD capacitors. However, I have heard that they may still be SMD even if their size is specified this way so I don't know which it is. [image]

Comment: Also consider that through-hole parts allow trace/track access to both sides of the PCB and any internal layers.  SMD parts need to have vias added (outside of the footprint) to access any other layer(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Package / Case": Axial

means exactly that: resistor on an "axis", i.e. a classical wired resistor.

Also, the dimensions have a "Dia.", i.e., a diameter. Only something that is round has a diameter.

Also, dead giveaway, first line:

> Category: **Through Hole Resistors**

If you're looking for SMD resistors, you'd have choosen the wrong category.

More indications:

- the [product page](https://www.digikey.de/en/products/detail/vishay-beyschlag-draloric-bc-components/MRS25000C2003FRP00/594534) also has a [datasheet link](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28724/mrs16m25.pdf)
- the picture top left [image: picture of THT resistor]
- the dimensional drawing [image: dimensional drawing]
- the "detailed description"

> 200 kOhms ±1% 0.6W Through Hole Resistor Axial Metal Film